# SQL query omits records in the process of being committed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm running a query every 5 minutes to extract records created/updated in the 5 minutes leading up to the scheduled job. Occasionally the query will omit records that appear to be in the process of being committed, but haven't fully completed. My current workaround is to delay the query by a couple minutes, but I'm wondering if there's a better way?

| order | line | recordDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-09-28 16:19:51 |
| 1 | 2 | 2022-09-28 16:19:52 |
| 2 | 1 | 2022-09-28 16:19:56 |
| 2 | 2 | 2022-09-28 16:20:00 |
| 2 | 3 | 2022-09-28 16:20:08 |

Here's an example of my query:

```
select *
from exampleTable
where recordDate between '2022-09-28 16:15:00' and '2022-09-28 16:20:00';
```

No records were returned in the query scheduled to run at 2022-09-28 16:20:00. The next run scheduled at 2022-09-28 16:25:00 returned all records related to order #2, but order #1 is completed omitted.

Has anyone else experienced this? Is there another way to not run my query until all pending commits are completed?

Comment: For the INSERT and SELECT statements are your datetime values all from the same source, ? Perhaps from GETUTCDATE()?

Comment: How can you tell they are in the process of being committed?

Comment: Also between is inclusive of both start and end datetime, so if a record was inserted at exactly the end of you range you'll include it twice... between is not generally a good solution `>= @StartDatetime and < @EndDateTime` is usually much better.

Comment: Typically if you need to do some processing of records on a regular basis, you store a flag against them as to whether they have been processed or not, which you update after processing. Then your query is just for unprocessed records. Having a date range is asking for trouble, because if for some reason the scheduled job doesn't run on time then how do you recover?

Comment: Elliveny -- datetime values are from the same source.

Comment: Dave -- I can't tell for sure they are in the process of being committed. I'm just basing it on the behavior of the query results. I'll be replacing the between function with your suggestion. Unfortunately, we're running SQL Server 2008 and don't have CDC available. I suppose I could add a boolean column to the table that defaults to false and is updated to true after my query runs and reverts to false after any update statement is performed.

Comment: Adding a bit column will be a lot more reliable than using a datetime range.

Comment: Is your database configured for `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT`? If order 1 was inserted but not committed in a long-running transaction, the query will miss it.

Comment: Dan -- Yes, the database is configured with `read_committed_snapshot` is on.